# Why does my function return a 0 or 1 at the end?

Tags: c++, boolean

I wrote a program to determine if a student passes for exams.  So it calculates the average and compares it with a limit and return it to the main.

It works (Which is great) but i keep getting a 0 or a 1 after each output. Im guessing this has to do with the boolean function. But im honestly not sure. At this point it feels like ive dug a rabbithole and see no exit.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

bool heeftToegang(float lab1, float lab2, float lab3, float toets1,
                  float toets2)
{
    const int kleinste = 0;
    const int hoogste = 10;
    const int toetsWeging = 3;
    int grens = 6;

    int gemiddelde = (lab1 + lab2 + lab3 +
               toets1 * toetsWeging + toets2 * toetsWeging) /
              9;

    string geen = " geen deelname";
    string oke = " => deelname oke";

    cout << "Lab: " << lab1 << " ; " << lab2 << " ; " << lab3
         << " Toets: " << toets1 << " ; " << toets2;

    // if else statement om de cijfers te checken
    if (lab1 > 8)
    {
        grens -= 0.5;
    }
    else if (lab2 > 8)
    {
        grens -= 0.5;
    }
    else if (lab3 > 8)
    {
        grens -= 0.5;
    }

    // check if var invalid
    if (lab1 == kleinste || lab2 == kleinste || lab3 == kleinste ||
        lab1 > hoogste || lab2 > hoogste || lab3 > hoogste)
    {
        cout << geen << " (Sprake van fraude)";
        return false;
    }
        // hier wordt er gekeken of het cijfer kleiner is dan 4
    else if (toets1 < 4 || toets2 < 4)
    {
        cout << geen;
        return false;
    }
    // check gemiddelde < 6
    else if (gemiddelde < grens)
    {
        cout << geen;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << oke;
        return true;
    }
}
int main()
{
    cout << heeftToegang(5, 5, 5, 6, 6) << endl;
    cout << heeftToegang(5, 5, 6, 6, 6) << endl;
    cout << heeftToegang(5, 6, 6, 6, 6) << endl;
    cout << heeftToegang(6, 6, 6, 6, 6) << endl;
    cout << heeftToegang(6, 6, 6, 5, 6) << endl;
    cout << heeftToegang(6, 6, 6, 6, 5) << endl;
    cout << heeftToegang(6, 6, 6, 7, 7) << endl;
    cout << heeftToegang(8, 8, 6, 5, 6) << endl;
    cout << heeftToegang(8, 8, 0, 7, 8) << endl;
    cout << heeftToegang(9, 9, 9, 3.9, 9) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << heeftToegang(9, 9, 9, 3.9, 9) << endl;
```

Will execute the `heeftToegang` function and output what was returned. Booleans are displayed as '0' or '1' when outputted with `cout` (you can change this with [`boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha)).

Your function does all the outputting that you want, so there's no need for you to output the boolean at the end. Change your function calls to just that--function calls!

```
heeftToegang(9, 9, 9, 3.9, 9);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::boolalpha` if you want to see "true" or "false" printed for bools. Otherwise they wilł be converted to integers and printed as the values `0` (for false) and `1` (for true) - note: any non-zero value is considered "true" in C++.